# Apple maps gives an overview instead of turn-by-turn navigation in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, apple-maps

I am using the below url to open apple maps and start navigation.

```
http://maps.apple.com/?saddr={currentPosLatitude},{currentPosLongitude}&daddr={destinationPosLatitude},{destinationPosLongitude}
```

Currently it opens apple maps and shows the directions. But when we click Go, it shows the overview instead of turn-by-turn directions. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: To get the turn by turn directions, don't supply a starting address, just a destination address, so try this url instead:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?daddr={destinationPosLatitude},{destinationPosLongitude}
```

This worked on my end to get the voice guided turn by turn directions. It seems to me that by supplying a starting address, Maps assumes you are not there. So the "starting" point needs to be your current location in order to get the voice guided turn by turn directions. By leaving the starting address out of the url that opens maps, you are telling it to use the current location as the starting point and thus are able to get turn by turn directions.

Original answer:

> This works on my end. Tested by opening your url (with set start and end positions) in a Xamarin.Forms WebView, which immediately launches the Apple Maps app, as expected. After clicking the Go button, I have to swipe at the top to see each step in the directions though.
>
> Screencast: https://screencast.com/t/KQPuENdSWQ
>
> Are you sure that the positions you are passing in can be resolved to actual addresses? As a test, I put in a position in the middle of the ocean and got a message that "Directions are not available to this destination."
>
> And this has nothing to do with Xamarin. Once you open that url, you are in the Apple Maps app and outside of any influence of Xamarin. All xamarin is doing is opening the Apple Maps app with the url that has the start and end addresses/positions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting the same thing when I search for an address. But the map does not update according to the user's location. When we search for the address directly using apple maps, the maps moves along with users location.

Comment: Figured it out. Updating the answer